# Do I need to maintain my Django SECRET_KEY when migrating users between builds?

Tags: django

We're currently working on upgrading our website from Django 0.9 to 1.4 along with a different host.  There are a fair number of users, so having everyone redo their password is extremely unpalatable.  While migrating the tables between MySQL instances running on the VPS's is relatively straightforward, do we need to also be sure to copy the `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py` in order to keep things transparent for the users?

From what I've read, it seems like `SECRET_KEY` is used for CSRF protection and password reset keys, but I'm not sure if it's also the password salt. If it isn't (is the user pass salted then?), is there some other solid reason to preserve the key between deployments?

Answer (score 1):

`SECRET_KEY` isn't used for password salts, but it's used to sign — among other things — session cookies and password reset links.

If you change it, your users will be logged out of their sessions, and password reset links that were generated prior to the change won't work anymore.

Passwords themselves won't be affected.